# email lands on spam, how can I get rid of that?

Tags: php

I attached an auto email sender with the file name sendemail.inc.php to be sending auto welcome once registered but it lands on spam. Is there any advise that can help?

Comment: Some suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161048/what-do-i-need-for-a-compliant-email-header

Comment: Please read this before asking a question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use transitional doctype in html emailer.
we define doctype for html while create page. the html emailer needs the same 
e.g.

Comment: If you could include an example snippet of what you mean that would improve the answer. Welcome to stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

> **It would be easier for us to understand why your email goes to spam, if you could attach your code with your question.**

There could be several reasons your email can land at spam at the receiver's end.

1. Check whether your server's IP is [blacklisted](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx). Email from a blacklisted IP address will reach the spam folder.
2. Check whether your domain's MX record is fine.
3. Check whether your reverse [MX A Records (PTR)](http://intodns.com/) points to your hostname or IP address
4. Check if your email content contains too much hyperlinks
5. Check if your email content contains abusive, marketing words
6. Check if your email content contains [spam trigger words](http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/30684/The-Ultimate-List-of-Email-SPAM-Trigger-Words.aspx) (e.g. Congratulations, won, $)
7. Try keeping your email in text format, rather than HTML format. It helps your email score. Otherwise include a text version of your email if you are sending HTML emails
8. Maintain a good text-to-image ratio
9. Avoid large attachments. If you really need to send large attachments, use something like Dropbox, Google Drive etc to send your file as a link.
10. Check if your email headers are properly set. If not, use something like [PhpMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/). It is a free PHP script, and does it's job pretty good.

Hope this helps.